# Prove that $f = g$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
\int_E f \, dm = \int_E g \, dm
$$
for every measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f = g$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

Proof

note that
$$
\int_E f \, dm = \int_E g \, dm
 $$
then

$
\int_E f \, dm -\int_E g \, dm =  0, 
 $ and by the property of Lebesgue integrals it holds that
$
\int_E (f -g) dm =  0
 $  then f=g almost everywhere

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The claim $\int_E f dm - \int_E g dm=0$ "almost everywhere" does not make sense because the left-hand-side is just a real number. What do you mean by "almost everywhere"?  Similarly $\int_E(f-g)=0$ "amost everywhere" does not make sense. If the functions $f$ and $g$ are measurable then you might consider the set $E=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\geq g(x)\}$.

Comment: @Michael yes those are real numbers, but my question was if that proof is correct o what can  I change?

Comment: How do you get from $\int_E (f-g)=0$ to $f=g$ almost everywhere!?This is pretty much assuming what is to be proven.

Comment: You removed the phrase "almost everywhere" which is good. But now your proof is basically a restatement of the given information. So it is not a proof. You want to use the fact that we can choose any (measurable) $E$ we like by choosing a good $E$ that leads somewhere. You might consider the $E$ I gave in my comment. I'm not quite sure what $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ means, though, if measurability of $f,g$ is included in that or not.

Comment: You did not say that $m$ is Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I uses that  $\int_{E} f \, dm =0$ iff f=0 almost everywhere  but that is  just for non-negative functions

Comment: Right, but you don't know that $f-g$ is non-negative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  ahhhh okey , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if $f$ is not non-negative almost everywhere, if you have that $\int_{E}f\,dm=0$ for all measurable $E$, then $f=0$ a.e.

Consider $E_{n}=\{x:f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. Then if possible let $m(E_{n})>0$.

Then you have that $\int_{E_{n}}f\,dm\geq \frac{1}{n}\cdot m(E_{n})>0$ which is a contradiction.

Hence $m(E_{n})=0$ for each $n$.

Hence, if $P=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}=\{x:f(x)> 0\}$, then $m(P)=0$ by subadditivity.

Similarly, if $M_{n}=\{x:f(x)\leq -\frac{1}{n}\}$, then by the same argument, $m(M_{n})=0$ for each $n$.

Hence if $N=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}M_{n}=\{x:f(x)<0\}$, then $m(N)=0$.

Thus $m(P\cup N)=m(\{x:f(x)\neq 0\})=0$

Thus $f(x)=0$ a.e.

Now apply this to $f-g$ to get that $f-g=0$ a.e. which means $f=g$ a.e.

Comment: In this case, you conclude the proof by considering the possible cases for the set $E$, that is, $\int_E (f - g) dm = 0$. From this, you consider the possible cases for the set $E$ and see that if $m(E) = 0$, this leads us to a contradiction.